# 15Bit Color Components, Bit shifting

Tags: c++, bit-shift

Okay bit shifting is still a bit weird to me.

I've got a 16bit value. The first 15 bits are colors and the last bit is alpha.

I have done this with 24 and 32 bit colors no problem as they are nice byte size's to deal with, but I cant seem to get this to work with 15/16 bits.

This is what I've done in the past, with 24/32 bit colors

```
(m_colorValue >> RED_CHANNEL) & 0xFF;
```

I'm trying to split the value into 4 values. 3 5 bit color values and 1 alpha value.
I don't know what mask I should be using.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? All I can tell from your question is that you have a 16 bit number and "something" isn't working. Code would be nice.

Comment: You forgot the question... what do you want to accomplish? What have you tried?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194449/converting-bitmap-from-argb1555-to-rgb8888 ?

Comment: @Mark I think extracting the channels and converting to 24 bit is similar, but not the same problem. So I wouldn't call it a duplicate.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, good point. The code in the answer would be a good starting point though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
red = (packed >> 0) & 0x1F;
green = (packed >> 5) & 0x1F;
blue = (packed >> 10) & 0x1F;
alpha = (packed >> 15) & 0x01;
```

packed should better be an unsigned and I'm probably off for the order.

Answer (score 1):

use bit shifting.

```
ushort s;
ushort b= s&0x1F // first five bits
ushort g= (s>>5)&0x1F // second five bits
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty vague, but if you're trying to extract the individual color components from an RGB1555 this should do the trick:

```
unsigned short color;

const unsigned int 
    a = color & 0x8000, 
    r = color & 0x7C00, 
    g = color & 0x03E0, 
    b = color & 0x1F;
```

Comment: Anding isn't enough, you have to shift too.

Comment: @Mark Um, yeah. I would think that OP would know the basics given that he's done with 24bpp/32bpp. I just provided the masks to get the components as his question doesn't even explicitly state what he's trying to achieve. If he states the full problem I suppose I could write a full solution for him...<sigh>